# Problema with aapt.exe with build tools 23.0.2: Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I created a simple project using Android Studio, but the build process is not finishing...

My project configuration:

**APP** **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        //Gradle Daemon Support for Faster Compilation
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.12.1230'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    // rastreamento de crashes do sistema
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.4.0'

    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'

    // Trabalhar com datas
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'

    //Socket.IO-client
    compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.2'

    //MATERIAL EDITTEXT
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Wed Oct 21 11:34:03 PDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

**Configuration on AS**

I know I'm not using the recommended version, but it doesn't make difference, because Android Studio is using the same version of the file gradle-wrapper

[image]

**THE PROBLEM**

[image]

It does not finish!

Is there something what I can do in this case?

**EDIT:**

I noticed this:

```
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Many processes in background of aapt:

[image]

Comment: Click gradle build Runnging to see if it download sth.

Comment: It downloaded all dependencies, but it does not finish the build process. If I delete the .gradle folder into my project, it starts to download everything again, but when it is going to finish (apparently), it remains in this state.

Comment: Try use  recommended version and wait some time .

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 possible solutions in windows :
the first check your local variables must have SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT = 30
and JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\ jdk1.8.0_65

if this does not work , then you must have the sdk damaged , remove it . the installation path , and C:user\username\ delete .android , .gradle , and any folder that has to do with Android Studio avoiding any possible cache that could produce the error , then re-download the sdk , that should work

Comment: Gradle bulding running task also were not stopping... as soon as I did set both LAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT and JAVA_HOME at windows 10, things gets ok.. I tried both at once...